# iOS APNS нет уведомлений

Tags: ios, push

PUSH уведомления замечательно приходили. До определённого момента, пропустили срок действия ключа. APNS стал соответственно ругаться. Ключ создали новый, APNS ругаться перестал, но уведомления на устройства перестали поступать. Код ни на сервере, обращающемся к APNS, ни на принимающих устройствах - не менялся. APNS молча принимает уведомления от сервера и дальше тишина. "Что я делаю не так?"

Comment: Отправку уведомлений делал для проверки отдельно вообще на другом языке - тоже самое в итоге. Может есть какие-то идеи, что могло поломаться, чего я мог упустить.

Comment: Нужно больше информации. Как было настроено? Что использовалось?

Comment: Всмысле как было настроено? Устанавливалось защищённое соединение, отправлялись данные APNS серверу. Раньше он присылал уведомления на устройства, а теперь нет. Наша серверная часть на C#, для эксперимента пробовал на PHP отправлять - результат тот-же - нету уведомлений.